# Are there published rebuttals of Patrick Flynn's recent book "The Best Argument for God"?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-religion, existence-of-god, classical-theism

[The Best Argument for God](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1644137801), by Patrick Flynn, was recently published on October 17th, 2023. With only 21 votes on Amazon so far, it has garnered an average rating of 4.9 (as of March 25th, 2024). Does anyone know if detailed rebuttals of this book have already been published?

---

The book's description on Amazon for reference:

> When the medieval theologian Thomas Aquinas addressed the best
> arguments against God in his masterwork, the Summa Theologica, he
> listed only two. The first was the problem of evil: How can God ― who
> is perfectly good ― exist alongside that which is against Him? His
> second: Is God really needed to explain the world?
>
> In this landmark work, Patrick Flynn presents the best arguments for
> God while also addressing the strongest objections. This book is
> destined to become the apologetic gold standard for defending
> classical theism against atheistic naturalism. Flynn clearly
> identifies what is at stake and then provides you with cogent,
> accessible, yet potent defenses to counter those arguments that
> atheists routinely make to justify their claim that there is no God.
>
> Flynn masterfully defines commonly misconstrued terms ― from worldview
> and intelligibility to scientism, ontology, and metaphysical intuition
> ― and illustrates them with real-world examples. He explains the
> Principle of Sufficient Reason and how it is used to support the
> reality of God. You also will acquire the foundation you need to
> understand the best philosophical arguments for God’s existence.
>
> Drawing from insights from philosophers Aristotle and Aquinas to
> Leibniz and Lonergan, you will find extensive philosophical reasons to
> accept and explain:
>
> - Two step-by-step cosmological arguments
> - How phenomena ― like consciousness and moral intuition ― confirm God's existence
> - The fine-tuning of creation (and why God ― and not the multiverse ― is the
>   best explanation of that)
> - Why the assertion that everything can be explained by science is unreasonable
> - Whether God can be falsified … and if that even matters!
> - Whether belief in a necessary being is embracing a “god of the gaps”
>
> With sidebar definitions and detailed explanations, Flynn guides you
> in learning authentic reasons for your belief in God. He evaluates
> whether it’s simpler to believe in God or not, and he provides
> numerous arguments from philosophy, science, and plain common sense.
> Additionally, you will discover how even the traditionally held
> attributes of God point to His existence.
>
> This seminal book turns the tables on and pokes holes in the theory of
> naturalism. Flynn’s in-depth analysis will give you the tools you need
> to share your belief in such a way that those who deny God’s existence
> will have to defend their view. Also featured is an appendix with a
> dozen additional objections and bulletproof replies for the existence
> of God.

Editorial Reviews

> "Flynn goes to great lengths to be charitable and to take on the very best argumentation to the contrary. Anyone looking
> for a primer on the best contemporary thought in the analytic Thomist
> vein should see Flynn's work as a reliable access point to this
> field."
> **James D. Madden, Ph.D., Professor of Philosophy, Benedictine College**
>
> "Pat Flynn presents a powerful and innovative case for the existence
> of God. He skillfully breaks new ground on classical Thomistic lines
> of inquiry. This book is a must-read for anyone interested in the
> latest and best work on the question of God's existence in an
> accessible style."
> **Joshua Rasmussen, Ph.D., Associate Professor of Philosophy, Azusa Pacific University**

About the Author

> Pat Flynn is a writer, philosopher, podcaster, and speaker living in Wisconsin with his wife, five children, and St.
> Bernard. He hosts Philosophy for the People and The Pat Flynn Show.
> His website is ChroniclesOfStrength.com

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152299/discussion-on-question-by-mark-are-there-published-rebuttals-of-patrick-flynns); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.